# How can I effectively delete all parent entities that have no children via NHibernate LINQ?

Tags: nhibernate

I have the need to periodically purge some of my database tables. The purging consists of deleting all parents that have no children. The current implementation uses a stored procedure to complete this task. What I'd like to have is to eliminate the stored procedure and achieve the delete action via a NHibernate Linq query. E.g. I need a query that deletes all Invoices that have no items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `QueryOver`, you can find out all the **persistent objects** of type `Invoice` that you wish to delete. But as Rippo said, this will fire several Delete queries. You can modify this a little and create an array of invoice Ids. And then create one SqlQuery that deletes all the records at once using `YourSession.CreateSQLQuery`.

```
var invoicesToDelete = YourSession.QueryOver<Invoice>().Where(invoice => invoice.items == null).List();
var invoiceIds = new List<int>();
foreach(var invoice in invoicesToDelete)
{
    invoiceIds.Add(invoice.Id);
}
string queryString = "delete from invoice where id in(";
foreach(var id in invoiceIds)
{
    queryString = queryString + id + ",";
}
queryString = queryString.TrimEnd(',');
queryString = queryString + ")";
ISQLQuery query = YourSession.CreateSQLQuery(queryString);
queryString.UniqueResult();
YourSession.Transaction.Commit();
```

The code looks messy, but it should be more efficient.

Comment: Currently I am using this construct:
            using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var notNeeded = Session.Query<Invoice>()
                .Where(m => !m.Items.Any());
                foreach (Invoice invoice in notNeeded)
                {
                    Session.Delete(invoice);
                }
                
                tx.Commit();
            } but it is very inefficient

Comment: I'll give it a try, but since there are usually several hundreds of invoices that should be deleted, I don't think this path is efficient either.

Comment: i think this is definitely faster than sending individual delete commands to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to fire lots of delete queries to your DB then the short answer using Linq or QueryOver you can't, unless you compose a list of ID's first then use that in a sub query. One shot deletes can be troublesome in any `ORM`

Most solutions use either a stored procedure or an embedded named query (either SQL or HQL).